# What does connect_timeout do/mean in Socket.IO 1.0.6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to find the definition of connect_timeout, when is it fired, what's the use for it?

Reading here : http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object)

Right now I have an app I tried to run without turning on the server, and it tries to connect and the event "Reconnecting" is fired for 4 attempts, one every 2 seconds. Then it says "Failed Reconnecting" when it hits the 4 attempt mark and fires the event "reconnect_failed".

I haven't been able to hit the connect_timeout event. How do I do that? When does it happen?

I was hoping Socket.IO had some sort of function of "CONNECTING" and then if it failed it would continue attempting "CONNECTING" and if that failed it would say "CONNECTION FAILED" and if it connected successfully at some point, it would then call "RECONNECTING" instead and if that failed after a certain amount of attempts it would say "RECONNECTING FAILED". Is that something that has to be programmed by me? I haven't seen it built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection timeout is when a client is connected to the server and it takes too long for a response to be received, causing the client to disconnect because it has stopped receiving anything from the server. This can be caused by faulty internet or if the client loses connection to the server (i.e. the clients internet becomes disconnected). This is true for most server based communications and is likely the same for socket.io.